# Swift AnyObject analog for structs

Tags: swift

Is it possible to specify type which accepts only structs?

I have some method which accepts NSCopying make a copy and manipulate on it. But it is safe to accept structs too because of value semantics.

Have swift something opposite to AnyObject which include Any but not object?